# How can I implement a character comparator to find whether a Deque is a palindrome?

Tags: java, iterator, palindrome, deque

I have a class `isPalindrome` where I take in a string, turn it into a Deque, and then find if the order of the Deque would be the same front front to back or from back to front. I have learnt about using iterators to aid myself in this task but there seems to be an issue when I try to run the code.

Here is my code so far:

```
public boolean isPalindrome(String word) {
        Deque<Character> L = new LinkedListDeque<>();
        for (int x = 0; x < word.length()-1; x++) {
            L.add(word.charAt(x));
        }
        if (L.descendingIterator() == L.iterator()) {
            return true;
        } else {return false;}
```

Can anyone please explain where am I going wrong in this. I've been trying to debug this code for ages. Any edits to my code and with explanation would be appreciated :)

P.S. My `LinkedListDeque` is pretty much this

```
public class LinkedListDeque<T> extends LinkedList<T> implements Deque<T> {


}
```

Comment: You need to iterate your iterator. The iterator itself is just another object, not the elements in the Deque. Also read about `==` vs `equals` in Java

Comment: I've read that as well but I'm struggling to understand how to do that. Can you please show with explanations as well?

Comment: And `LinkedList` already implements `Deque`, no need to wrap it in another class

Comment: can I do while (L.iterator().hasnext) {if L.iterator == L..descendingIterator) {return true} return false;   Does that iterate over the iterator as well?

Comment: No, because you cannot compare iterators. You have to compare their elements, not the iterator itself. I have written an answer explaining/showing this.

Answer (score 0):

An iterator itself cannot be compared. You must *iterate* over it to get the values of the underlying collection (that's where the name comes from).

```
final Iterator<Character> asc = L.iterator();
final Iterator<Character> desc = L.descendingIterator();

// both iterators have the same underlying collection, so `hasNext` _must_ return the same value for both
while(asc.hasNext() && desc.hasNext()) {
  if (!Objects.equals(asc.next(), desc.next()) {
    // characters are different, definitely not a palindrome
    return false;
  }
}

// both iterators fully consumed without finding an offending character => a palindrome was found
return true;
```

`Iterator#hasNext` checks if there are more elements that have not yet been visited. `Iterator#next` moves the iterator forward by one, i.e. it consumes the element, and returns it.

A few more observations about your code:

- `==` compares memory addresses, not the values of objects
- `Iterator` instances do not implement `equals`, as such they cannot be compared
- No need to create a new `LinkedListDeque` since `LinkedList` already implements `Deque`
- `ArrayDeque` is another Deque type that does not suffer from the same memory overhead as `LinkedList`
- This algorithm fully iterates over the deque twice, forward and backward; which is inefficient (double the amount of work). It would suffice to stop when both iterators meet in the middle (but the iterator interface does not provide such functionality. Perhaps using a `ListIterator` could help avoid this). For simple and short inputs this won't be a problem though.